# how to iterate 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2d array called `myarr[3][3]` and I want to to get `myarr[0][0]`, `myarr[0][1]`, and `myarr[0][2]` in another 1d array called `arr1[3]`. The same for `myarr[1][0]`, `myarr[1][1]`, and `myarr[1][2]` in another 1d array called `arr2[3]`, and so on.

How can I do something like that in Java?

I have tried to use for loop but I stopped and couldn't know what to write inside it.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++){
        //what can i write here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an explicit `for` loop, you could use [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-). These are the method signature and description:

```
arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array.

Then, to copy the contents from `myarr[0]` to `arr1` you could do:

```
System.arraycopy(myarr[0], 0, arr1, 0, arr1.length);
```